# selectize not displaying search results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, selectize.js

I am trying to implement Remote Source in Selectize.

I am accessing data from api. The format is as follows:

```
concept_id,name
228,Pelecypoda
286,Pelecypoda
```

When I try to console item in render, it doesn't get consoled. But when i console in success the data is consoled.

```
$('#search_text').selectize({
    theme: 'name',
    valueField: 'url',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: 'name',
    options: [],
    create: false,
    render: {
        option: function(item, escape) {
            console.log(item);
            return '<div>' +
                '<span class="title">' +
                    '<span class="by">' + escape(item.name) + '</span>' +
                '</span>' +
                '<span class="description">' + escape(item.concept_id) + '</span>' +
            '</div>';
        }
    },
    score: function(search) {
        var score = this.getScoreFunction(search);
        return function(item) {
            return score(item) * (1 + Math.min(item.watchers / 100, 1));
        };
    },
    load: function(query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://192.241.245.176:4567/api1",
            dataType: 'text',
            type: "GET",
            data: {
                q: query,
                page_limit: 10
            },
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(res) {
                var result = {};
                result.name = d3.csv.parse(res);
                console.log(result);
                callback(result.name);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Try consoling `result.name`

Comment: Yes i tried that and it is consoled @Owlvark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a key value standard being forced but the documentation doesn't cover it very thoroughly. It's mentioned in there once in passing but isn't discussed any further.

You have to return your result from the server with the properties of name and value:

name=>namedata

value=>valuedata

Cliffnote: $items[$i]['name']['id']

Cliffnote: $items[$i]['value'][$key]

in my case building my result looks like this PHP code.

```
    $group['location'] = range(0,5);
                                        //'street',
                                        //'city',
                                        //'county',
                                        //'state',
                                        //'country',
                                        //'country2',

    $group['property']  = range(0,4);
                                        //'title',
                                        //'property_sub_type',
                                        //'subdivision_name',
                                        //'sub_cat',
                                        //'interior_features',

    $group['school']    = range(0,2);
                                        //'junior_high_School',
                                        //'middle_school',
                                        //'high_school',

    $group['mls']       = range(0,1);
                                        //'mls_area'
                                        //'mls_id#'
    $items = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($res); $i++)
    {
        $items[$i]['name']['id'] = array_shift($res[$i]);
        $offset          = 0;
        foreach ($group as $key => $val)
        {
            $items[$i]['value'][$key] = array_filter(array_slice($res[$i], $offset, count($group[$key])));
            $offset += count($group[$key]);
        }
    }
```

resulting in this data structure

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 119
                )

            [value] => Array
                (
                    [location] => Array
                        (
                            [street] => 25700  Cliff Cir  
                            [city] => Spicewood
                            [county] => Travis
                            [state] => Texas
                        )

                    [property] => Array
                        (
                            [property_sub_type] => Single Lot
                            [subdivision_name] => Lakecliff On Lake Travis Sec 01
                        )

                    [school] => Array
                        (
                            [junior_high_School] => N/A
                            [middle_school] => Marble Falls
                            [high_school] => N/A
                        )

                    [mls] => Array
                        (
                            [mls_area] => 12
                            [mls_id#] => 4434048
                        )

                )

        )
```